# swift 4 combinations func

Tags: arrays, swift, combinations

```
func combinations<T>(of array: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
    return array.reduce([[]]) { combihelper(a1: $0, a2: $1) }
}

func combihelper<T>(a1: [[T]], a2: [T]) -> [[T]] {
    var x = [[T]]()
    for elem1 in a1 {
        for elem2 in a2 {
            x.append(elem1 + [elem2])
        }
    }
    return x
}
```

What's the best solution to write the code in one func and more swifty?

Comment: Could you provide a description with an example of what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, sure. It gives you combinations of parameters. For example, var par = [[Double]]()

par.append(Array(stride(from: 0, through: 10, by: 1.0)))
par.append(Array(stride(from: -10, through: 0, by: 1.0)))

let comb = combinations(of: par)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to combine both methods into a single one just change a1 to $0 and a2 to $1:

```
func combinations<T>(of array: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
    return array.reduce([[]]) {
        var x = [[T]]()
        for elem1 in $0 {
            for elem2 in $1 {
                x.append(elem1 + [elem2])
            }
        }
        return x
    }
}
```

---

```
let multi = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]]
combinations(of: multi)  // [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [2, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], [3, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [5, 0]]
```

---

Extending Collection, constraining the element to RangeReplaceableCollection and using higher-order functions we can came up with:

```
extension Collection where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection  {
    func combinations() -> [Element] {
        reduce([.init()]) { result, element in
            result.flatMap { elements in
                element.map { elements + CollectionOfOne($0) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let strings = ["12345","1234567890"]
strings.combinations()  // ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "10", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "20", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "30", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "40", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "50"]
```

Comment: Well, it turned out to be very simple)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it without any for loops:

```
func combinations<T>(of array: [[T]]) -> [[T]]
{
   return array.reduce([[]]){ c,a in c.flatMap{ e in a.map{e + [$0] } } }
}
```